# Runtime Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I have this `Ionic` project which I wanted to include Firebase Cloud Messaging in it. I've had a couple of errors after trying to test FCM on it, so I troubleshot it and after installing some packages and updating other stuff, such as npm, typescript and such, this is last error I couldn't really find an answer for. I haven't changed anything in the code itself as I found many answers such as infinite loop and so on. I'm not sure how updating some packages as I mentioned before could have done this. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

The error message:

Runtime Error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _ValueOutputAstTransformer.visitStringMap (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:141973:42)
    at visitValue (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:122510:24)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:141975:51
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _ValueOutputAstTransformer.visitStringMap (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:141974:26)
    at visitValue (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:122510:24)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:141975:51
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _ValueOutputAstTransformer.visitStringMap (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:141974:26)
    at visitValue (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:122510:24)
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks like recursion without an end condition. Possibly `visitValue` calls something on itself, rather than children?

Comment: Hi bolot, yea seems like it. What intrigues me is that I haven't really changed anything to this code, I only updated my typescript version, I did an npm update, but I haven't changed it, so for me it's very hard to understand how solve this, I may have to re-install a certain package or roll back?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it could have been an issue with the Angular version. I have done more package updates and it had evolved to other errors, clearer errors at least. So the issue related to this topic has been resolved by updating the Angular version and applying the updates using the following commands:

## Install npm-check-updates

$ npm i -g npm-check-updates

## Run npm-check-updates with -u, will upgrade package.json

$ ncu -u

## Install updated packages

$ npm install